# Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-3931

Tags: wso2-esb

One of our WSO2 ESB (4.8.1) log shows this error intermittently, What actually causes this error?

TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-07-08 09:30:09,982]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler} -  http-outgoing-6409: Connection time out while in state: REQUEST_DONE {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-07-08 09:30:09

TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-07-09 12:08:10,018]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} -  Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-3931 {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-07-09 12:08:10,319]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler} -  http-outgoing-7634: Connection time out while in state: REQUEST_DONE {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-07-09 12:08:10,319]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} -  ERROR_CODE : 101507 {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-07-09 12:08:10,319]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} -  ERROR_MESSAGE : Error in Sender {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-07-09 12:08:10,320]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} -  ERROR_DETAIL : Error in Sender {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-07-09 12:08:10,320]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} -  ERROR_EXCEPTION : null {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-07-09 12:08:10,320]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} -  FaultHandler : AnonymousEndpoint {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-07-09 12:08:10,320]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} -  Endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-07-09 12:08:10,320]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} -  Suspending endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint - current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Thu Jul 09 12:08:40 IST 2015 {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-3931

The above log says that the connection between the client and the ESB got timeout before ESB sends the response to the client. By default this timeout is 60 seconds (the socket timeout of http listener). So ESB is taking more than 60 seconds to send a response to the client. Reason might be because of your slow backend. You can increase this socket timeout of the passthrough http transport by adding `http.socket.timeout=120000` to `passthru-http.properties` file in $ESB_HOME/repository/conf/ directory. Here socket timeout is set to 120seconds

> WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler} - http-outgoing-6409: Connection time out while in state: REQUEST_DONE

The above log says that the connection between the ESB and the backend got timeout before ESB gets the response from the backend. By default this timeout is 60 seconds (the socket timeout of http sender). So your backend is taking more than 60 seconds to respond. You can increase the socket timeout of the passthrough http transport by adding `http.socket.timeout=120000` to `passthru-http.properties` file in $ESB_HOME/repository/conf directory. Here socket timeout is set to 120seconds

Please follow [this](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/05/wso2-esb-a-guide-to-troubleshoot/) troubleshoot guide to configure timeout values correctly.

Comment: hi depository, thank you for the response. I've already set the http.socket.timeout value to 120000. Have to check the backend service as to why its intermittently taking more than 120seconds to respond.